# Angular: How to conditionally apply Validators for Reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Reactive form and have declared the form in this way.

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }
public ngOnInit(): void {
    let ipRegex = /^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})*$/;
    let form = {
    ipaddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(ipRegex)]],
    port: ['', [Validators.required]],
    username: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]],
    enablepassword: ['']
    };

    this.deviceForm = this.fb.group(form);
  }
```

I want to make password form field mandatory based on Boolean condition provided by a method. I tried to put that method directly next to the Validators.required like [Validators.required, this.myFunction()] as this.myFunction returns Boolean value. But I'm getting error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular forms have a built in function `setValidators()` that enables programmatic assignment of Validators.

For your example you can do:

```
if(someBool){
this.deviceForm.controls['password'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
}
```